# With devise, how do I create a sessions#create endpoint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I’m using devise 4.2 with with Rails 4.2.  I want to enable a session creation endpoint, so I have specified this in my routes file

```
    devise_scope :user do
      post 'sessions' => 'sessions#create'
      delete 'sessions' => 'sessions#destroy'
    end
```

And upon running “rake routes,” I can see this endpoint generated

```
                                                    auth_sessions POST     /auth/sessions(.:format)                                                                                       auth/sessions#create {:format=>"json"}
```

This is the class I’m using

```
class Auth::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  layout false
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
end
```

But upon POSTing

```
{  
    "user": {
        "email": "myuser@email.com",
        "password": "password",
        "remember_me": 1
    }
}
```

To the endpoint

```
http://localhost:3000/auth/sessions
```

I get a 404.  What am I missing?  What else do I need to do to enable this endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I think endpoint should be: `http://localhost:3000/user/sessions` or you should change `devise_scope :auth`